# Close Bootstrap Modal after AJAX return

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a Bootstrap 3 modal that has data that is passed to it via data-attributes, this data is dynically retrieved from the server so it's not static html. I am then submitting the data with a form button asynchronously to PHP.

All of that is fine the only problem is I can't seem to get the modal to hide when I have pressed submit I have tried a few things without success.

So passing stuff to modal like so (which is isn't static but retrieved from AJAX data):

```
$('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
  var ID = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-id');
  var URL = $(e.relatedTarget).attr('data-url');
  $(this).find('#id').val(ID);
  $(this).find('#url').val(URL);
});
```

Here's the submit function:

```
$(document).ready( function() {
  $('.modal form').on('submit', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault()
    $.post( $(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function(data) {
      console.log(data)
      if(data.return===true) {
        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
      } else {
        alert('error');
      }
    }, 'json')
  })
});
```

The modal:

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-sm">

    <!-- Modal content-->
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;    </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">ID: <span class="ID"></span> <span class="URL"></span></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-inline" action="print.php">
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="hidden" name="id" id="id">
            <input type="hidden" name="url" id="url">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

My modal's id is myModal, also there is nothing being logged in the web console however I can see the response payload and it does contain a value which is '`done`' that I've set.

[image]

Any help would be appreciate.

Comment: does it `alert('error');`? Also; dont use Pascal Casing for CSS class names, but use e.g. `my-modal`. Where is the code that shows the modal, please post this.

Comment: @Richard there isn't an error and the data is passed and a response is returned as shown in the screenshot. I have updated with the modal html. Cheers

Comment: Is it possible that when you create the modal, it creates it twice (add a `console.log` there also)? So when you close it, there are already 2 of them

Comment: @Richard There is absolutely nothing wrong with Pascal Casing for CSS class names. Or do you have a source stating otherwise?

Comment: @DouwedeHaan nothing wrong with it, but just prone to more errors and the industry standard is hyphenation, not Pascal Casing. While we're here, might as well educate people

Comment: Nothing wrong with camelCasing is there? Either way I have json encoded the response and now able to log it more specifically and get the result I required. Thanks

Comment: if i am not wrong the response shows `done` against the line `console.log(data)` which is text and not `json` so obviously `data.return` is nothing and it would never call the `$.modal("show")`

Comment: Yes that was the case you're correct.